# MapKit doesn't show Blue Dot for Current Location

Tags: iphone, mapkit, core-location

I am a newbie in MapKit for iPhone and tried to implement this, for some reason I can't see the current location blue dot, anyone else had this issue????

```
#import "DetailMapViewController.h"
#import "mapAnnotations.h"

@implementation DetailMapViewController

@synthesize inStock;

-(void)getlocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)loc
{
    location = loc;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Street View";
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    mapView.delegate=self;      
    //MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 5000, 5000);

    mapAnnotations *ann = [[mapAnnotations alloc] init];
    ann.title = @"";
    ann.subtitle = @"";
    ann.coordinate = region.center;

    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];
}


- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];

    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation)
    {

        annView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"blueDot"];
        if (annView != nil)
        {
            annView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        else
        {
            annView = [[[NSClassFromString(@"MKUserLocationView") alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"blueDot"] autorelease];


        }
    }

    if([inStock isEqual:@"yes"]){
        annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    } 
    if([inStock isEqual:@"no"]){
        annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    }
    if([inStock isEqual:@"unknown"]){

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greyPin.png"]];
        [annView addSubview:imageView];




    }
    annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    return annView;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: I see you have showsUserLocation = Yes, that should do the trick unless you didn't connect the XIB file to mapview control to the Controller?

Comment: Have you ensured that your current location is within 5000m of `location` above?

Comment: I ave not ensured that I am in 5000m - I never used XIB files.

Comment: Are you trying to show the "blue dot" AND other pins that indicate inStock?

Comment: Are you running this inside the Simulator? In that case your current location is Infinite Loop, Cupertino.

Comment: Yeah but it still doesnt showthe current location

Comment: The other pins show up but not teh blue dot

Comment: Are the location services enabled? In 4.0 or later you can check the value of  [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]

Comment: This is out of subject,whatever my question is, will i able to see my current location in simulator??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way the viewForAnnotation is currently written, it should actually crash when trying to show the current location because the "blue dot" annotation view doesn't have the pinColor or animatesDrop properties.

Try changing it to the following:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:MKUserLocation.class]) {
        //user location view is being requested,
        //return nil so it uses the default which is a blue dot...
        return nil;
    }

    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];

    if([inStock isEqual:@"yes"]){
        annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    } 
    if([inStock isEqual:@"no"]){
        annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    }
    if([inStock isEqual:@"unknown"]){
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greyPin.png"]];
        [annView addSubview:imageView];
    }
    annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    return annView;
}
```

On the simulator, the user's location will be Cupertino, CA, USA (a little south of San Francisco).  If your own annotation is not within 5000 meters of that, you won't see the blue dot.  You'll have to zoom out to see it.

Comment: This is out of subject,whatever my question is, will i able to see my current location in simulator??

Answer (score 3):

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

Comment: If you read the question carefully, you'll see he already uses this property.

Comment: I had set this property on initialization, but after location authorization was granted I had to set it again for some reason to make the blue dot appear again